# Updating Text Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new with Flutter and I face a problem as I want to update Text widget with the value passed from numbers() function.

The problem is the value inside Text does not change on the screen when I press on the button but it changes in the console.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {


int n = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [

        Text(n.toString()),

        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
            n += numbers();
            print(n.toString());
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
int numbers (){

  List<int> numbersList = List(1);

  numbersList[0] = 30;

  int n1 = numbersList[0];

  return n1;

  print(numbersList[0].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to update UI then you should be call `setState((){});` method in flutter.This method available in `StatefulWidget`

You Should be implement below way

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int n = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(n.toString()),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  n += numbers();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

int numbers() {
  List<int> numbersList = List(1);

  numbersList[0] = 30;

  int n1 = numbersList[0];

  return n1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This how you can change it

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: (){
     final newVal = numbers();
     setState((){
              n += newVal;
             });
   print(n.toString());
       },
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected since in flutter whenever you want to "refresh" screen you have to call `setState()` for the widget that you want to update. So what you do is, inside your onPressed function you do the following:

```
setState(){
   n += numbers();
}
print(n.toString());
```

You can read more about stateful widgets and setState [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)

Comment: Thank you I will look at setState functionality